# Adding Node.js to Existing .net Application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, node.js

I need some help here...

I have a fully functional .net web application with MVC structure and using API's.

Now I need to implement node.js functionality on one of the pages. I am not sure where to start..what to do... read through a lot of articles but still don't have a clue.

Can some one give me step by step instructions, how can add a node.js script files and how to call those functions from already existing javascript functions.

It's really so confusing to start with.

Please help

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "need to implement node.js functionality on one of the pages" -- this doesn't really make any sense. Can you try and explain better? What does NodeJS have to do with your .NET app?

Comment: Hi I have a page , that need to feed live data. So i want to use node.js but i am not sure where to start or how to start